# I want to create an RDD in Spark with two columns from a txt file. How do I do it?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataset, pyspark, rdd

I want to create an RDD in Spark with two columns from a txt file.

Following is my code:

```
dataset = pd.read_fwf(FILE, colspecs=col, header=None, index_col=0,
                   names=['first','second','third'])

set = sc.parallelize(range(len(dataset)), 10)

first_second = set.map(lambda z: (dataset['first'][z], dataset['second'][z]))
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pandas to read in your txt file, you can first create Spark DF and then you are able to access the colums e.g.

```
dataset = pd.read_fwf(FILE, colspecs=col, header=None, index_col=0, names=['first','second','third'])

set = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataset)

first_second = set.map(lambda z: (z.first, z.second))

# another possibility
first_second = set.map(lambda z: (z["first"], z["second"]))
```